# Error in reviews2$Rating : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, deep-learning

Hello I am having an issue with a vector. I attached the error message below. Does anyone have an idea how to fix the issue?

```
    library (keras);library (tensorflow);install.packages("tensorflow")
     install_tensorflow(version = "1.12"); install_keras(method = "conda")
     library(ggplot2); library(magrittr);
     library(dplyr); library(tm); library(tidyr); 

     devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
     devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")


reviewscl <- read.csv("C:/Users/Astrid/Documents/Master BWL/Data Mining  mit R/R/Präsentation 2/Womens Clothing Reviews3.csv")
  reviews2<-reviewscl%>%
    unite(Title, Review.Text, sep=" ")
  reviews2 <- gsub("NA", "", reviews2)

  reviewStars<-as.numeric(reviews2$Rating)
  reviews3<-cbind(reviews2, reviewStars)

Error in reviews2$Rating : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `gsub` to replace all NA's. If you use `gsub` it returns you a string vector. As the error message says you can't use $ with vectors. So a possible solution is to change reviews2 to a data frame:

```
reviews2 <- as.data.frame(reviews2)
```

If you post an example data frame I maybe could help you a little bit more :)

Answer (score 0):

When you used gsub, most likely the entire df was coerced into a character vector. Once it is a vector the $ operator is not allowed. If all you want is replace NA then you can try the following in place of gsub.

```
reviews2[is.na(reviews2)] <- ""
```

I am away from computer but this is my best guess to retain the reviews as a df.

Please let me know, how it worked out.